# Why Does (a) print (0)?

Tags: java

i am trying to grasp the idea of ObjectOriented programing can someone explain why the local variable (a) prints zero instead of the set int that is placed in the getter and setter.

These are the objects in the AppClass

```
Symptoms obj = new Symptoms();
test obj2 = new test();
```

actionPerformed... i think this is all you need from the AppClass

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt((field.getText()));
    obj.setSleep(x);
    writeSleep();
    frame.setVisible(false);
    obj2.tester();
    readSleep();
    initialize2();
    }
```

This is the Symptoms class that i hope to add more symptoms if i can get this to work

```
public class Symptoms {
private int sleep;

public int getSleep() {
    return sleep;
}
public void setSleep(int sleep) {
    this.sleep = sleep;
}
}
```

this is the tester class where i hope to print out the value of (a)

```
public class test {
public void tester(){
    Symptoms get = new Symptoms();
    int a;
    a = get.getSleep();
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

It seems as tho the test class isnt getting the "message" but if i run the same code in the AppClass, given i modify the code a little bit, then (a) will print.

Comment: Does this code compile ?

Comment: Because of default values of class members.

Comment: For questions of the form, "why isn't my code working?", best is to create and post your [mcve].

Comment: Where do you ever set sleep? A better question is "why would you expect `a` to have any value **other** than 0?" Serious.

Comment: yeah, the code compiles with no exceptions or errors... just prints 0

Comment: if i set  a = get.getSleep then the return value should be assigned

Comment: int x = Integer.parseInt((field.getText())); sets obj.setSleep(x); which sets public void setSleep(int sleep) { this.sleep = sleep;} which is called by Symptoms get = new Symptoms(); in which (a) is set by a = get.getSleep();

Comment: @Kujo016 you never assigned `sleep` and I can't see how `actionPerformed` is related here.

Comment: You set a, with sleep , but as noted above **never assign anything to sleep**. So it remains 0. Again, why would you expect a to be anything but 0?

Comment: int x = Integer.parseInt((field.getText())); sets obj.setSleep(x); which sets public void setSleep(int sleep) { this.sleep = sleep;} which is called by Symptoms get = new Symptoms(); in which (a) is set by a = get.getSleep();

Comment: You never call `setSleep` in your tester class. If you think you do, show it to me. Walk through your code logic in your mind always to see what it's doing. It's  a great exercise that will help you see the error in your assumptions above, and in learning how code works.

Answer (score 6):

Because the JLS says so, see chapter [4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
>
> For type `int`, the **default value is zero**, that is, 0.

Now after you saw it's confusing, I recommend you to explicitly set it to zero in the future, it's clearer.

Comment: i set x to 0 in the class and in the instance and it still produced a = 0 in the test class.

Answer (score 1):

In `test.tester()`, an instance of `Symptoms` is created and the method `setSleep()` is never called with it, so `getSleep` returns the default value of `a`, which is 0.

You only ever call `setSleep` in `obj.setSleep(x);`, where `obj` is an entirely different instance from `get`. But since `x` is not `static`, calling `obj.setSleep` doesn't change the value of `get.x` -- only the value of `obj.x`.

Comment: how do i set setSleep() in one class and get getSleep() in another is what i am basically asking. i kno whow to use the objects but i think that is the problem.

Comment: @Kujo016 If you want setSleep/getSleep to refer to the same variable, then either you should use the same instance, or mark `x` as static.

Answer (score 0):

here is a better version of the question and the answer. It has nothing to do with setting int to zero.

[How to set and get with three Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176369/how-to-set-and-get-with-three-classes)