# How to set and get with three Classes?

Tags: java

I have a similar question on this topic but I dumbed it down and left out all the extra code. Also, I took the advice of the old question and set my variables to zero but it didn't make any difference.

Main:

```
public class WhyAPrints0Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 24; 
    WhyAPrints0 set = new WhyAPrints0();
    WhyAPrints01 get = new WhyAPrints01();
    set.setWhy(x);
    get.print();
}

}
```

Class 1

```
public class WhyAPrints0 {
private int why;

public int getWhy() {
    return why;
}

public void setWhy(int why) {
    this.why = why;
}
}
```

Class 2

```
public class WhyAPrints01 {
WhyAPrints0 get = new WhyAPrints0();
int a = 0;

public void print(){

    a = get.getWhy();
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

I really don't understand why this doesn't print 24 so if someone could explain well and possibly fix the code to where it does I would really appreciate it.

Comment: First thing: please start by giving your classes and methods better names. You making the whole thing unnecessary confusing by using names that are very hard to distinguish. Then: you are setting the field "why" to 24 in one object; and then you print the field "why" (which was initialized to 0) of ANOTHER object. So, why are you surprised that when something "that knows 0" returns 0 when asked for it?

Comment: You set a value on one object, and then are printing from the other.  Why would the second one know anything about what you did to the first?

Comment: What relation is there between the `WhyAPrints0` instance in your `WhyAPrints01` and the one in your `main` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link your `WhyAPrints01` to your `WhyAPrints0` some how. Right now you have 2 instances of `WhyAPrints0`. You can change your `WhyAPrints01` to something like this so you can set an instance of `WHyAPrints0` in your `WhyAPrints01` class.

```
public class WhyAPrints01 {
    WhyAPrints0 get;
    int a = 0;

    public WhyAPrints01(WhyAPrints0 get){
        this.get = get;
    }

    public void print(){
        a = get.getWhy();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

And your main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 24; 
    WhyAPrints0 set = new WhyAPrints0();
    set.setWhy(x);
    WhyAPrints01 get = new WhyAPrints01(set);
    get.print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the exact help i needed. i didnt know how to link the two and i didnt know what i was asking to do. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to print `24`?

You invoke the `print()` method:

```
get.print();
```

Which prints `0`:

```
public class WhyAPrints01 {
    WhyAPrints0 get = new WhyAPrints0();
    int a = 0;

    public void print(){
        a = get.getWhy();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

(Since `0` is the default value for an `int`, which is what is returned by `get.getWhy()`.)

I *think* your confusion is coming from the concept of having multiple instances of the same class.  You have *two different instances* of `WhyAPrints0`.  One in your `main()` method and one in your second class.  These two instances have *nothing to do with one another*.  Setting a value in one doesn't affect the other.

As an analogy, consider two identical cars.  If you put something in the trunk of one car, you shouldn't expect to retrieve it from the trunk of the other car.  It doesn't matter that the cars are otherwise identical, they're not the same car.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a little more sense. I was just thinking it was like a storage for a value that i could retrieve at any point. i thought once it was set it was set and it was only changed if it was initialized by the single "set" in any class. Thank you.

Comment: @Kujo016: You can make use of `static` variables to do that.  It's important to learn the difference between `static` and non-`static` class members, as just tossing in the `static` keyword to "make it work" would result in a lot of confusing and difficult errors in the future.